# SQL Server 2000: Monitor replication

Tags: replication, sql-server

starting with (Microsoft) SQL Server 2005, there are stored procedures available to monitor replication (http://www.g-productions.nl/index.php?name=sp_replmonitorhelppublication)

But as we are a bit slow, there are some SQL Server 2000 left and we want to monitor their replication status

I didnt have success with backporting these sp's...so help would be highly appreciated!

Comment: SQL2000? Really?

Comment: `I didnt have success with backporting these sp's` - please be more specific. What did you try and what were the results? We can't just guess.